# Build a 3rd party API / Use javascript2img.com in your php

Tags: javascript, php, forms, api

I would like to obfusicate a js code over javascript2img.com

The user should imput for example their name, that will be insertet in a php file into the whole js code and then submitet to javascript2img.com

After that it should return the obfuscated code on my page that the user can simply copy it.

You can simply post the code to http://javascript2img.com/obfuscating.php but i don't know how i get the outputed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push POST request to http://javascript2img.com/obfuscating.php with correct varibales and parse obfusicate js code

Your can use Tab Networks in Chrome browser.

Take a look

[image]

Please google 'php CURL' and 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser'

Comment: I tried it out but i can't get the code in the responce. Its just a emty textbox...

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/tz8p9cyb/